# Google Cloud - cannot detach shared VPC from project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I hope some of you are able to help me as my GCP Projects are completely bricked at the moment. I cannot for the life of me get a Shared VPC to detach from a project.

- I followed the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/deprovisioning-shared-vpc
- Found someone with a slightly similar issue here: [Google Cloud Platform - Find Resource by Full Resource Name](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016015/google-cloud-platform-find-resource-by-full-resource-name)

I removed all resources (Cloud Run, Compute Instances) from the client project, then:

```
gcloud compute shared-vpc associated-projects remove my-client-project --host-project my-host-project
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.shared-vpc.associated-projects.remove) Could not disable resource [my-client-project] as an associated resource for project [my-host-project]:
- Invalid resource usage: 'The resource 'projects/my-client-project/global/networkInstances/v-809269519-3cf0c736-8058-45a1-b397-6755a9e759e1' is still linked to shared VPC host 'projects/my-host-project'.'.
```

While I cannot detach this shared VPC, both projects are in a completely un-usable state. Can someone please advise on how I can fix this?

Just to make this abundently clear; I deleted everything on the project except for 1 machine image and 1 external IP that I cannot simply throw away as I'll need it soon. The only thing that ever used this shared VPC was a CloudRun service, but I have since deleted all CloudRun services. I can find nothing in the service project that should be causing this error. The service project also has no 'Private service connection' or 'Serverless VPC access' or 'VPC network peering.'

It's basically an empty project. If it wasn't for the fact I need the host project to stop being a host project ASAP, I'd just throw the service project away. But that takes 30 days so it's not an option.

Comment: Could it be that something went wrong and did not delete it some resource that could not being possible to detach the VPC. My recommendation is to contact [link] (https://console.cloud.google.com/support) GCP Support in order to have more elements for a deep analysis

Comment: GCP support isn't free unfortunately. I just bit the bullet and deleted the project without detaching the shared VPC first. Hope it'll be OK in 30 days. Redicilous.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by:

- first go to the VM that uses a subnet in the Shared VPC
- shut down VM
- Edit VM: Change network to local network instead of Shared VPN's subnet
- Now the Shared VPN has still the VM's project attached. Go to Shared VPN, detach VM's project (now this step worked for me!)
- Start VM

Comment: And ideas when the connected service is a Cloud Run app? I've deleted the service but the problem persists.